# Entity Framework can not see updated values of other sessions

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I use EF 6.1.3 and Oracle. There are two sessions. In first session I can not view 
the updated values of second session.

```
using (var uow = new DmsUOW()
{
    var var1 = uow.RoleTypeRepository.Get(p => p.ID == 3).Single().NAME; // var1 = ADMIN5
    //I change my data ADMIN5-> ADMIN6 from other session(TOAD) and commit. 
    var var2 = uow.RoleTypeRepository.Get(p => p.ID == 3).Single().NAME; //var1 = ADMIN5 ---> WRONG!!! it must be ADMIN6
 }
```

Repository :

```
public class DmsUOW : UnityOfWorkEF
    {
        private ROLE_TYPE_Repository _roleTypeRepository;
        public ROLE_TYPE_Repository RoleTypeRepository
        {
            get { return _roleTypeRepository ?? (_roleTypeRepository = new ROLE_TYPE_Repository(this)); }
        }
    }
```

RepositoryEf class:

```
public class RepositoryEf<TEntity> :BaseRepositoryEf, IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{

    protected DbSet<TEntity> objectSet;

    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression)
    {
        return objectSet.Where(expression).AsQueryable<TEntity>();
    }
 }
```

myDbContext settings :

```
Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```

But when I write sql query It works fine:

```
using (var uow = new DmsUOW()
{
    var var1 = uow.RoleTypeRepository.GetMyQuery(3).Single().NAME;
    var var2 = uow.RoleTypeRepository.GetMyQuery(3).Single().NAME;
}
```

RoleTypeRepository :

```
public class ROLE_TYPE_Repository : RepositoryEf<ROLE_TYPE>
{
    public ROLE_TYPE_Repository(IUnityOfWork UnityOfWork) : base(UnityOfWork) { }

    public List<ROLE_TYPE> GetMyQuery(int? id)
    {
        return this.Query<ROLE_TYPE>("SELECT * FROM ROLE_TYPE WHERE id = :p1", new OracleParameter("p1", id)).ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a `DbContext` caches by default its values when they are read from the database (you will find all your cached instances in the `DbContext.Set<EntityType>().Local` collection, and a `DbContext` will check the `Local` collection before issuing a command to the database)

You have several options:

1. Use a new `DbContext` instance. This should be the preferred way... `DbContext` instances are not meant to be long-lived (much less if you use the unit-of-work pattern, which for your context variable name, you are using)
2. Refresh the entity from the database before using it:

   ```
   var var1 = uow.RoleTypeRepository.Get(p => p.ID == 3).Single().NAME;
   // Refresh before reading it
   uow.Entry(var1).Reload();
   var var2 = uow.RoleTypeRepository.Get(p => p.ID == 3).Single().NAME;
   ```
3. Detach your entity before reading it again:

   ```
   var var1 = uow.RoleTypeRepository.Get(p => p.ID == 3).Single().NAME;
   // Detach before reading it
   ((IObjectContextAdapter)uow).ObjectContext.Detach(var1);
   var var2 = uow.RoleTypeRepository.Get(p => p.ID == 3).Single().NAME;
   ```
4. Don't track your entities so they don't get cached:

   ```
   var var1 = uow.RoleTypeRepository.AsNoTracking().Get(p => p.ID == 3).Single().NAME;
   // Something has changed the item
   var var2 = uow.RoleTypeRepository.AsNoTracking().Get(p => p.ID == 3).Single().NAME;
   ```

Comment: Excellent. I have choiced 4. 
Besides even it caches the values it sends the query to DB. We tracked session queries. Why does it do like that? 
By the way AsNoTracking has no Find method? How can I implement it?
 
 public virtual TEntity GetByID(object id)
        {

            return objectSet.AsNoTracking().Find(id);
        }

Comment: @AdemAyg for performance reasons: sending a query to the store/database is (typically) way more expensive than just checking an in-memory collection.

Comment: Besides even it caches the values it sends the query to DB. We tracked session queries. Why does it do like that?  2.question : y the way AsNoTracking has no Find method? How can I implement it? public virtual TEntity GetByID(object id) { return objectSet.AsNoTracking().Find(id); } – @Jcl

Comment: Using `AsNoTracking()` should not cache the entities (if it does, then there's something wrong, or you are reading your entities somewhere else where you didn't use `AsNoTracking()`). As for `Find` in your case, you can implement it like `return objectSet.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id)`